# Section on Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse in the Deep Learning book

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am reading the following section in the Deep Learning book by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville.

[image]

I have some questions.

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $Ax=y$, then we can have left inverse $B$ such that $x=By$ only when the nullspace of the matrix $A$ is $\{0\}$, because if $Ax=0=y$ for some $x\neq 0$ then there is no $B$ such that $0\neq x=By=0$. In other words, the dimension of rowspace, and hence the rank of $A$, must be $n$.

Thus, if $A$ is taller than it is wide, $m>n$, then it is possible for the left-inverse to exist. On the other hand, if $A$ is wider than it is tall, $m<n$, then the rank can be at most $m$, which means that $A$ cannot have left-inverse.

However, in the screen-shot I have attached, it shows the exact opposite: If $A$ is taller than it is wide, then it is possible for this equation to have
no solution. If $A$ is wider than it is tall, then there could be multiple possible solutions.

Where I have gone wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: The Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse is based on the Singular Value Decomposition of the original matrix $A$. SVD is defined for all matrices. Therefore, the assertion that $A$ cannot have a left-inverse if the rank of it is at most $m$ is wrong. In that case $A$ does indeed defines an indeterminate system of equation but that does not mean that this system is not solvable, just that it has multiple solutions. For starters just consider, the pseudo-inverse $A^+$ of $A$ as a special matrix such $AA^+A = A$ that is computationally quite expensive to get but convenient theoretically to exist.